# Typing <svelte:component>'s "this" property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, svelte

I am building kind of a portal system in Svelte using a store to pass a component to display somewhere up the component tree.

My problem is not about implementing that system, it is about typing the store. I tried to declare it like so:

```
const modalComponent = writable<SvelteComponent>(null)
```

But this doesn't work. When I import a component somewhere, VS Code shows me a type of `typeof <componentName>__SvelteComponent_`, which is not compatible with the `SvelteComponent` type (which is actually an alias of `SvelteComponentDev`):

> Type 'typeof <component>__SvelteComponent_' is missing the following properties from type 'SvelteComponentDev': $set, $on, $destroy, $capture_state, and 2 more.

How am I supposed to type this? I would like to avoid using `any`.

**Update**: here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-sid-du7fy) of what would reproduce the case. Unfortunately, I can't seem to be able to get it to work with TypeScript. I'm still sharing it, hoping it can help.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal reproductible example (probably using [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)). Can you also provide the way you import the type. Where did you get the `.d.ts` I didn't find it on `DefinitelyTyped`.

Comment: I'll try and setup a codesandbox. For typings, I just followed the official Svelte blog post about TS support : https://svelte.dev/blog/svelte-and-typescript. It includes a section about the tsconfig file to use (with a specific `include` config value)

Comment: Could you open an issue at https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues for this? This is something we have not considered and need to investigate how to fix this.

Comment: Do you mean an issue about my origin post or about the codesandbox that I can't get working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT (2023)**
It's now fixed and should be typed `writable<typeof SvelteComponent>`.

*(Yes it's been fixed a long time ago, sorry :D )*

---

As @dummdidumm instructed me, I created an issue [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/language-tools/issues/486) for the team at Svelte to fix that.

In the mean time I will mark this as the answer for now and will update it as soon as the issue is fixed and released. Thanks!

Comment: It's fixed now. You should also note that it's `writable<typeof SvelteComponent>`, not `writable<SvelteComponent>` in your answer.

Comment: I had the same issue in the latest version of svelte(3.58). I managed to get it working by switching to typescript version 5.0.4, instead of 4.9.5